# Are java servlet containers capable of asynchronous I/O processing without additional threads?

Tags: java, servlets

For frameworks like Node.js and ASP.NET Core, they are capable of processing requests asynchronously for I/O tasks without creating additional threads.  Are java servlet containers also capable of doing this?  If not, do java servlet containers wait I/O tasks in the thread until the request is fully processed?

Comment: I'm not sure about servlet containers but I'd assume most use a thread-per-request approach. However, there are frameworks like Vert.x which work very similar to Node.js etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself.

According to the [Jakarta EE 9 documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#asynchronous-processing),:

> There are two common scenarios in which a thread associated with a request can be sitting idle.
>
> - The thread needs to wait for a resource to become available or process data before building the response. For example, an application may need to query a database or access data from a remote web service before generating the response.
> - The thread needs to wait for an event before generating the response. For example, an application may have to wait for a Jakarta Messaging message, new information from another client, or new data available in a queue before generating the response.
>
> These scenarios represent blocking operations that limit the scalability of web applications. **Asynchronous processing refers to assigning these blocking operations to a new thread** and retuning the thread associated with the request immediately to the container.

So, java servlet containers are capable of asynchronous processing.  However they will create new thread for both I/O and CPU bond tasks, which is not the same model as Node.js and ASP.NET Core.